# Is it possible to conditionally apply transclution to directive?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to decide whether to apply transclusion to an element based on a scope variable ?

For example ( Stupid simplified reduced example of what i'm trying to achieve )

```
app.directive('myHighlight', function () { 
  return {
    transclude : true,
    template : "<div style='border:1px solid red'><span ng-transclude></span></div>"
  }
});

app.directive('myDirective', function () { 
  return { 
    template : "<span>some text</span>",
    link : function (scope,element,attr) { 
        if ( 'shouldHighlight' in attr) {
          // wrap this directive with my-highlight
        }
    }
  }
});
```

And then in the html

```
<span my-directive></span>
<span my-directive should-highlight></span>
```

Note, please don't tell me to just add the highlight instead of should-highlight, as i said this is a dumb reduced example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of optionally applying the highlight directive, *always* apply it and do the optional wrapping inside that directive.  The optional wrapping is achieved with an `ng-if` and a boolean passed from `myDirective` to `myHighlight` via markup:

`<div my-highlight="someBooleanValue">some text</div>`

The `myHighlight` template:

```
<div ng-if="actuallyTransclude" style="border:1px solid red">
    <span ng-transclude></span>
</div>
<div ng-if="!actuallyTransclude" ng-transclude></div>
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/X6eB5/

Comment: Thanks for the advice but my problem is that the transcluded directive is passed as meta data so i'm trying to find a way to inject it by name (similar to the $controller service). I need to conditionally apply different transcludded directive to different templates.

Comment: ah, well. how bout an upvote for the effort then? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  When you specify the transclude option, you know that you can declaratively indicate where the content should go using ng-transclude.

In the linking function of the directive, you will also get a reference to a transclude function (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile, see link section):

```
function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller, transcludeFn) { ... }
```

The transcludeFn will return the transcluded content, so you can conditionally insert that were and when you want to in the link function of your directive.

Example (http://jsfiddle.net/DKLY9/22/)

HTML

```
<parentdir flg="1">
    Child Content
</parentdir>
```

JS

```
app.directive('parentdir', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        scope: {
            flg : "="
        },
        transclude : true,
        template : "<div>Parent {{childContent}} Content</div>",
        link : function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl, transcludeFn){
            if (scope.flg==1){ 
                scope.childContent="Include Me instead";
            } 
            else {
                scope.childContent = transcludeFn()[0].textContent; 
            }
      }
    }
});
```

This is a simplified example.  To get a better idea of how to use the transclude function, refer to the following : http://blog.omkarpatil.com/2012/11/transclude-in-angularjs.html

Answer (score 0):

When I approach these kind of problems I just look at what angular did. Usually their source code is very readable and easy to re-use. ngTransclude is no different:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngTransclude.js

I leave the rest to you. You can either create your own transclusion directive that receives also a condition, or just duplicate the code into your specific directive when the if condition is true.

If you still have trouble, please let me know and we'll set up a plunker.